# How to fix out the laravel data insert problem

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have tried to insert the student data into database . All data were passes to controller. But not inserted. Please tell me how to fix out this problem?

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
       //dd($request->all()); exit;
       $validData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'id' => 'required',
        'father_name' => 'nullable',
        'address' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'father_phone' => 'nullable',
        'email' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
      ]);

     Student::create($validData);
     session()->flash('success', 'Student created successfully.');
     return redirect(route('student.index'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$validData` on `Student::create($validData);` as below

```
 Student::create($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you put your model code here? Or make sure you have defined all Fields as 'fillabale' in model?

Comment: this is not an answer. please avoid giving this type of answer. you can comment when you will have enough reputation :)

Comment: Well, this can be an answer. He's state valid point here. Its unfortunate that the guys doesnt have enough reputation. Be kind and fare mate